# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to load a prediction after unpickling but I'm getting this error

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py:29:
>   DeprecationWarning: numpy.core.umath_tests is an internal NumPy module
>   and should not be imported. It will be removed in a future NumPy
>   release.   from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:311:
>   UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from
>   version 0.20.2 when using version 0.19.2. This might lead to breaking
>   code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   UserWarning)
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:311:
>   UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from
>   version 0.20.2 when using version 0.19.2. This might lead to breaking
>   code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   UserWarning)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rf_pred_model_tester.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       print('Class: ',int(rf.predict(xx)))   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py",
>   line 538, in predict
>       proba = self.predict_proba(X)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py",
>   line 581, in predict_proba
>       n_jobs, _, _ = _partition_estimators(self.n_estimators, self.n_jobs)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/base.py",
>   line 153, in _partition_estimators
>       n_jobs = min(_get_n_jobs(n_jobs), n_estimators)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 464, in _get_n_jobs
>       if n_jobs < 0: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

here is the code that i am trying to run

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
with open('rf_model_1','rb') as f:
    rf=pickle.load(f)

xx = np.array([67, 17832, 1, 1, 0, 33, 1941902452, 36, 33011.0, 19, 18, 0, 2, 1]).reshape(1,-1)
print('Class: ',int(rf.predict(xx)))
```

I'm expecting a result like this :

```
Class:  [0]
```

if i run the code on jupyter its working fine but, i'm getting error when i try to run on terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Your error put it bluntly:

> UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from version 0.20.2 when using version 0.19.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.

And indeed that is what happened; when pickling, your RandomForestClassifier's attribute **n_jobs** was kept at **None**. This is the default value for initialization, but behind the scenes this is usually set to 1. You can find more details on n_jobs here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n-jobs

For you, setting rf's n_jobs to 1 will do the trick:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
with open('rf_model_1','rb') as f:
    rf=pickle.load(f)

rf.n_jobs = 1

xx = np.array([67, 17832, 1, 1, 0, 33, 1941902452, 36, 33011.0, 19, 18, 0, 2, 1]).reshape(1,-1)
print('Class: ',int(rf.predict(xx)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting this error when trying to unpickle my predictive model inside a Docker application and I was suspecting it had something to do with my Pickle version or Sklearn version, just couldn't figure out the exact reason. The n_jobs part at least solves my problem